# How can there be two potentials at this point?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

In this potentiometer configuration, The blue circled junction has potentials $V$ and $E$ at the same time (Galvanometer shows no deflection), Why is this so? What conceptual error have I made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$E$ and $V$ are the potential differences between the positive and negative terminals of the two batteries, and not the potential at the circled point.

Assuming negligible resistance wires, the potential of the positive terminals of the two batteries and the circled point has to be the same since they are connected together.

Now you might ask, "what is the potential at the circled point?", to which I would answer, it depends on what point in the circuit is assigned a potential of zero volts. While technically an arbitrary decision, typically that point is one that is shared with multiple components or the negative terminal of a battery.

For example, if the negative terminal of the upper battery is assigned a potential of zero volts, then the potential at the circled point would be $V$ volts. If the potential of the negative terminal of the bottom battery is assigned a potential of zero volts, then the potential at the circled point would be $E$ volts. The potential at any point in the circuit is the voltage measured between that point and the point assigned a potential of zero volts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also note that if you tried to ground both of the negative terminals, you'd end up with a [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)) and one battery would end up pumping current the "wrong way" through the other.  This is probably not a Good Thing.

Comment: To clarify:  if you put one of the leads of your voltmeter at the circled point, where are you putting the other lead?  Potential is _between_ two points, not at a single point.  The shortcut of assuming the other point is the ground rail doesn't work since you have two different voltage sources here.

Comment: @JDługosz Potential difference is between points. Potential is at a point. But you can only talk about the potential at a point if you define the zero potential reference point. Then clearly the potential at that point is the same as the potential difference between that point and the zero potential reference.

Comment: For example if you assign the negative terminal of the upper battery as zero potential, you connect the black lead  of the dc voltmeter to that terminal and the red lead to the circled point to determine the potential at the circled point.  Then the value you measure is both the potential at the circled point and the potential difference between that point and the point of zero potential.  To determine the potential at any other point in the circuit, move only the red lead to that point

Comment: In circuit analysis, we use Kirchhoff’s voltage law (KVL) to determine loop currents and Kirchhoff’s current law (KCL) to determine node voltages. For the latter, we assign a point in the circuit as the common, or zero potential point. Then using KCL each calculated  node voltage represents the potential at that node with respect to the zero potential reference.

Comment: @BobD: There is no "potential" except "relative potential", so sometimes "potential" (alone) ends up being used as a shorthand for "potential difference".

Comment: @BenVoigt IMO essentially yes